# AudioKit Recorder example crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, audiokit

I'm trying to understand why I got an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when using the AudioKit Recorder example on an iPhone. This happens when the iOS app is opening. This will help me to debug an app I'm working on!

Since I've updated to Mojave, Xcode 10.2 and Swift 5, the app I'm working on crashes and throws an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when I attempted to use

```
plot.node = mic
```

where those variables are declared as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var plot: AKNodeOutputPlot!
let mic = AKMicrophone()
```

So I tried to find out what causes this error and I realized that there is the same issue with the Recorder example, which also uses  `AKNodeOutputPlot`. All lines that set the node to AKNodeOutputPlot, such as `plot?.node = mic`, throw an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. Moreover, the following lines create the same error in the example:

```
frequencySlider.callback = updateFrequency
resonanceSlider.callback = updateResonance
frequencySlider.range = 10 ... 20_000
frequencySlider.taper = 3
```

The HelloWord example does not crash and there is no code that sets the node to AKNodeOutputPlot.

I installed Audiokit 4.7.1 using CocoaPods.

Would you have any tips or ideas to solve this issue and to make the Recorder example (and so my app) work again?

**EDIT:**

Please check [Github issue #1770](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/1770).

Thanks!

Comment: You could try following this opened ticket, and have your comments there too!: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/1762 and this one might be related: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/1530

Comment: Hello Glenn, thanks for you reply! Those tickets are related to AKMicrophone and mine is related to AKNodeOutputPlot and I don't know what I could try to solve my problem in those tickets. I will propably open a ticket on Github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [Github issue #1770](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/1770). Thanks!